# Partially update a rest resource

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a resource which has over 300 attributes. While trying to update it right now I send all 300 attributes which get inserted to the db from the api.

Needless to say that there are multiple problems with this.

1. someone can easily override others updates.
2. too much overhead sending all 300 attributes.

I am trying to convert this to a partial update instead of full update. I did some research and found that I can use HTTP verb **PATCH** to do this.

However I am stuck how to implement this. My precise problem is how to figure out which attributes to update.

e.g lest say I have following 3 attributes.

> {
>
> ```
> "showABC":"true",
>
>  "abcRequire:"true",
>
>
>  "abcReceipt":"false"
> ```
>
> }

Now lets say I am updating "**abcReceipt**" to "**true**", so my request json will look like something

> {
>
> ```
>    "abcReceipt":"true"
> ```
>
> }

Now when I convert this to JAVA Bean on the api side, all the other attributes(**which are not sent in the json,i.e showABC and abcRequire**) in the bean will be set to default values. i.e false in this case.

And at that time if i will save that bean, I will override the actual values for **showABC** and **abcRequire**.

So my question is how do I convert the request json to java bean without overriding the original values of the attributes which are not sent in the request.

P.S i want to avoid reflection. Also please keep in mind that I have over 300 attributes.

Comment: You will have to retrieve the actual object first, change the value that came into your request and only then update it.

Comment: As you already have a JSON representation, you might want to have a look into [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/). For the actual question: load the entity from the DB, update the field and store it back into the DB? Maybe also your database layer or entity management framework support partial updates.

Comment: @JorgeCampos : thats exactly my problem. How do i figure out what came in the request. Because once i convert the json request to Java Bean, Everything which did not come in the request will set to default value. (false in case of boolean) and after that point i do not know if It was false because that's what was sent in the request or it was set to default value.

Comment: You don't actually send just the updated fields to the service. A PATCH request contains instructions the server should execute in order to transform a document into the desired state, hence the client has to calculate the necessary steps and send them to the server. Please read this well-written [blog entry](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). You should also not map the payload directly onto your DB entity but apply the steps contained in the request within a transaction (either all or none have to succeed) if you want to be compliant with the spec